# Deleting the certificates from credential storage

Tags: android, ssl, certificate

In my Android app i am using the Key Chain to load the certificates and work with them.

Now if my certificate is deleted from the credential storage , how should the application handle it. ?
While application is running, the certificate is not loaded every time from the key chain as it can be a time consuming asyncrhonous operation, it is cached in the memory. So any server calls goes through from the cached data.

When the application is killed , this situation is fine because at that time i am trying to load the certificate from key chain.

I know the broadcast intent with action  "ACTION_STORAGE_CHANGED" is fired in API Level 16.
But how do we handle in Pre API level 16 apps ?

Is there any way to query the credential storage with the alias name?

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the same type of functionality - you would have to write your own service that runs in the background and check of your keys are in the keychain and are valid.

I'm writing my own app and am dealing with a problem similar to yours. a background service seems like the best approach for devices running API 14/15.

Good luck!